# show children of each parent in html laravel

Tags: html, laravel

i have stuck with this table format for months. so, i still trying to make my parent data show with children data beside the parent in tables.
here is what format that i try todo.
[image]

controller:

```
$task = Task::where('type', $this->type)->where('domain', $this->domain)->where('category', $this->category)->get();
        foreach ($task as $item) {
            $item['userTask'] = UserTask::where('task_id', $item->id)->whereDate('created_at', '>=', $this->firstDate)->whereDate('created_at', "<=", $this->lastDate)->get();
        }

        return view('export.task', [
            'task' => $task
        ]);
```

and here is the html tables:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Domain</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Detail</th>
            <th>Scope</th>
            <th>Activity</th>
            <th>Technician</th>
            <th>Photo</th>
            <th>Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach ($task as $item)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $item->domain }}</td>
                <td>{{ $item->category }}</td>
                <td>{{ $item->desc }}</td>
                <td>{{ $item->scope }}</td>
                <td>{{ $item->activity }}</td>
                <td>{{ $item->code }}</td>
                <td>{{ $item->dimension }}</td>
                <td>{{ $item->weight }}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

i have try loop the userTask data in td, but it not work.
**i really need your help, thankyou**

Comment: Do you need to make a table for each row of UserTasks or for Tasks?

Comment: Do you have a relationship set in between the two models?